# Exception raised executing Oracle SP with Table and Record Types

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I'm evaluating JOOQ, Oracle -> Java generation went smooth.  However I'm having an issue calling an SP which expects a Table Type as an IN PARAMETER

```
XxFooRecTypeRecord record = new XxFooRecTypeRecord();       
record.setPreferenceStartDate(new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));        

XxFooTabTypeRecord table = new XxFooTabTypeRecord();
table.set(record);

Preferences procedure = new Preferences();
procedure.setPPreferenceRec(table);
procedure.execute(configuration);
```

Gives me the exception PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PREFERENCES'

For Stored Procedures that use primitives (string, number, etc) it works as expected.

Further in the log I see:

```
2014-11-21 13:23:29 DEBUG LoggerListener:258 - Calling routine : { call "XXAR"."XX_AR_FOO_PKG"."PREFERENCES"(?, ?, ?) }
```

But I don't see the bind values log line.

Comment: What version of jOOQ are you using? Could you provide the stored procedure signature for `PREFERENCS` (i.e. the package specs)? Does it have 3 IN parameters, or are the others OUT parameters? What do you get when you turn on trace logging?

Comment: Solved, the problem was that I had not set the SQLDialect to Oracle.   The JOOQ version is 3.4 and the call works now.